# Laravel Buglinjo/WebP does not save image

Tags: laravel, webp, image-optimization

I'm having trouble using Laravel-WebP (https://github.com/buglinjo/laravel-webp).

I did the installation as described on the page, as my laravel is version 5.8 disregarded the specific instructions for laravel less than or equal to 5.4.

Here is the fileupload debug

```
UploadedFile {#233 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "B99700000_630509527083_main_17_Online_72DPI.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\Users\esira\AppData\Local\Temp"
  filename: "phpFABF.tmp"
  basename: "phpFABF.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\Users\esira\AppData\Local\Temp\phpFABF.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\Users\esira\AppData\Local\Temp\phpFABF.tmp"
  aTime: 2019-03-06 18:16:36
  mTime: 2019-03-06 18:16:36
  cTime: 2019-03-06 18:16:36
  inode: 0
  size: 65310
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\Users\esira\AppData\Local\Temp\phpFABF.tmp"
}
```

Here's my WebP code

```
WebP::make($request->arquivoEnviado->path())->save( storage_path('app/public/produtos/arquivo.webp'), 70 )
```

$request->arquivoEnviado->path() = Path of the temporary file.

```
dd($request->arquivoEnviado->path());
"C:\Users\esira\AppData\Local\Temp\php1FBB.tmp"
```

storage_path('app/public/produtos') = Destination folder.

When I debug the code "dd( WebP::make($request->arquivoEnviado->path())->save( storage_path('app/public/produtos'), 70 ) )" the return is true, but nothing appears in the folder.

Other information.

When I enter the filename in the destination path the debug returns false, if I put only the destination folder it returns true.

Certainly I'm not sure how to use WebP correctly, but unfortunately his documentation leaves nothing to be desired.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue, I found that it's required to install `cwebp` extension on the server and put the path in file `laravel-webp.php` as shown as below.

```
'drivers' => [

    'php-gd' => [],

    'cwebp' => [
        'path' => 'cwebp',
    ],

],
```

For reference: https://github.com/buglinjo/laravel-webp/issues/3